# Xcode 8 Fastlane build with TeamCity codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, teamcity, xcode8, macos-sierra, codesign

I've got a weird serious problem with Xcode 8.3.2 on macOS Sierra. I could build the app locally on build machine with fastlane or manually executing commands. Both development and ad-hoc build can be created locally.

```
 $ fastlane <lane_name>
```

But when tried the same from TeamCity it throws following error.

```
 [exec]/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 5609CEE02FBF256EDBF60DB28C1A2995A2153B5B --entitlements /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<AppName>-frpvxgdtafatrrgbjqbbepgfzvak/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SabaMeeting/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/<AppName>.build/Release-iphoneos/<AppName>.build/<AppName>.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<AppName>-frpvxgdtafatrrgbjqbbepgfzvak/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SabaMeeting/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/<AppName>.app
 [exec] /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SabaMeeting-frpvxgdtafatrrgbjqbbepgfzvak/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SabaMeeting/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/<AppName>.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
 [exec] Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
 [exec] 
 [exec] ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
 [exec] 
 [exec] 
 [exec] The following build commands failed:
 [exec]     CodeSign /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SabaMeeting-frpvxgdtafatrrgbjqbbepgfzvak/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/<AppName>/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/SabaMeeting.app
 [exec] (1 failure)
```

TeamCity pulls the code and even executes the commands but fails.
           Build Step: Command Line is set TeamCity with a custom script.
Tried following ways but not working:

1. Xcode Preferences ->Accounts->Delete already added account and add it again
2. Generated new Distribution and Developer Certificate and installed in KeyChain. New Provisioning Profiles and installed in Xcode.
3. Verified keychain access to private keys by "Allow all applications to access this item". Moved Certificates from login to System with access control to all.
4. Reinstalled xcode 8.3.2, restarted the machine.
5. Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority is installed.
6. Verified resource fork, finder information, or similar detritus not allowed in the app and derived data directory. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1940/_index.html
7. The project doesn't use CocoaPods.
8. Tried clearing DerivedData.

Any many more r&d. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like code signing is not matching with your local machine.... Can you share more information? screenshot of the provisioning profile part of the Xcode project, what fastlane command is this failure comes after from gym, match, sigh?  Are you using `use_legacy_build_api:true` in your fast file ?

Comment: I am not using automatic code signing. use_legacy_build_api:true is deprecated as of Xcode 8, so I am not using it. As I said fastlane is executing and creating build locally on build machine, but not when triggered from TeamCity. http://imgur.com/a/lI63T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does your lane look like on your fastfile? Please share it...

My guess;

*3 Verified keychain access to private keys by "Allow all applications to access this item". Moved Certificates from login to System with access control to all.*

Teamcity is probably not accessing to your certificates and failing.

Try this;

1. Move certificates back to login from system.
2. Add following before your `gym` or whatever fastlane command is building the .ipa. This will let teamcity unlock and access to keychain.

lane :beta do |options|

```
  unlock_keychain(path:"login.keychain", password:"yoursystempassword") 
  sh "security set-keychain-settings -t 3600 -l ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"   
  gym(scheme: "yourapp", workspace:"probably you dont have a wokrspace so no need")   
end
```

Comment: I have kept the fastlane simple for now as below
lane :app_distribution do
    gym(
      scheme: <schem_name>,
      export_method: "ad-hoc",
      clean: true,
      output_directory: "./build",
      buildlog_path: "./build/logs"
     )
  end
Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @u.gen, it worked. Any issue with System KeyChain? Many in past system only worked for me.

Comment: Jenkins or Teamcity scripts are always having trouble to access the keychain , I dont know why. So unlocking the key chain and setting a timeout with great number works.